# Open file on combobox selection

Tags: c#

I have a combobox which gets the list of items from the name of files I put together in one directory, the purpose for this is to make it dynamic - I'm very new to c# and it didn't occur to me a different way. - Here's the code for that bit:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(templatePath);
        foreach (string file in files)
            cbTemplates.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
```

Basically, that works just fine, it populates my combobox with the names of the files I have in that path, the problem is that I need to open the file that's selected in the combobox and read its contents and place them in labels, I was thinking maybe StreamReader would help me here but I have NO clue on how to implement it, I've searched the internet but it looks like no one had the same idea before me.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  A link to something similar or a guide of the objects I need to use would be great, thanks!

Comment: Hm, that is really a very new idea. Use a File.ReadAllLines function instead of the StreamReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help folks but I figured out how to get around my issue, I'll post the code for future incidents.  pd. Sorry it took me this long to reply, I was on vacation

```
string[] fname = Directory.GetFiles(templatePath); // Gets all the file names from the path assigned to templatePath and assigns it to the string array fname
        // Begin sorting through the file names assigned to the string array fname
        foreach (string file in fname)
        {
            // Remove the extension from the file names and compare the list with the dropdown selected item
            if (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) != cbTemplates.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                // StreamReader gets the contents from the found file and assigns them to the labels
                using (var obj = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file)))
                {
                    lbl1.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl2.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl3.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl4.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl5.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl6.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl7.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl8.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl9.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    lbl10.Content = obj.ReadLine();
                    obj.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is store the names of the files in a single separate file (csv or xml).  then use this file to both load the combobox and as an indexer.

for example lets say you have files a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt.  you should (as you already are) read the file names programmatically  THEN write them to a new file in whichever format you want, including a unique index scheme (numbers work fine).

your csv might look like this:

```
1, a.txt,
2, b.txt,
3, c.txt,
```

from here you can parse the newly created csv to your liking.  Use it to populate your combobox, index being its value and filename its text.  Then you can read your combobox selectedvalue, get the proper filename from the csv index, and finally open the file.

It may be longwinded but it'll work.  You could also just use a multidimensional array, but this is more fun from an educational stand point, and it will help you with read/write operations.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy to understand your problem. Do you want just to display filename w/o extension in your combobox? I hope this code will be usefull to you.

```
internal class FileDetail
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
public partial class Example: Form // This is just widows form. InitializeComponent is implemented in separate file.
{
    public Example()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        filesList.SelectionChangeCommitted += filesListSelectionChanged;
        filesList.Click += filesListClick;
        filesList.DisplayMember = "Display";
    }        
    private void filesListClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(_baseDirectory);
        filesList.Items.AddRange(
            (from fi in dir.GetFiles()
            select new FileDetail
            {
                Display = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name),
                FullName = fi.FullName
            }).ToArray()
        );
    }
    private void filesListSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var text = File.ReadAllText(
            (filesList.SelectedItem as FileDetail).FullName
        );

        fileContent.Text = text;
    }
    private static readonly string _baseDirectory = @"C:/Windows/System32/";
}
```